# Google sheet, select columns within a named range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to select a range of data within a named range on a google sheet but after searching I still can't figure it out how to do it.

In this case, I would like to count the amount of time a club appeared within a gameweek.

Here I can do it for all the gameweek tables I have, there is no problem.

[Total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1xm.png)

`=QUERY({B:C;D:E;F:G;H:I;J:K}; "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' AND Col1 <> 'GK' AND Col1 <> 'DEF' AND Col1 <> 'MID' AND Col1 <> 'FW' AND Col1 <> 'EXTRA' AND Col1 <> 'Club' AND Col1 <> 'count' AND Col1 MATCHES '^.{0,5}$' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")`

But I'd like to do the same for each of the gameweek table. So far I have this

[Gameweek 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYoXM.png)

`=QUERY({(B6:B15):(C6:C15);(D6:D15):(E6:E15);(F6:F15):(G6:G15);(H6:H15):(I6:I15);(J6:J15):(K6:K15)}; "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")`

but it is not very usable as I'd have to change each range for every next table.

So I tried to make the "Gameweek 1" table as a named range `gw1_clubcount` and only select its adequate columns similarly as the total so that I would just have to change that for each gameweek but obviously it is not working but that's what I would like to reach.

[Gameweek 1 with named range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvqg.png)

`=QUERY(gw1_clubcount {B:C;D:E;F:G;H:I;J:K}; "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")`

I've found the INDEX function where you can select the desired row and column of the named range.That would give something like this below but that's not how you use it.

`=QUERY({INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,1):INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,2);INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,3):INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,4);INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,5):INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,6);INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,7):INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,8);INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,9):INDEX(gw1_clubcount,,10)} ; "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")`

I'm not very experienced with sheets and a little help would be very appreciated !

Comment: maybe this other question can guide you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975801/update-named-range-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created a solution that requires custom function:

**To write a custom function:**

> 1. Create or open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> 2. Select the menu item Tools > Script editor.
> 3. Delete any code in the script editor.
> 4. For this problem, simply copy and paste the code below (stack function) into your script editor.
> 5. At the top, click Save save.

**To use custom function:**

> 1. Click the cell where you want to use the function.
> 2. Type an equals sign (=) followed by the function name and any input value — for example, =DOUBLE(A1) — and press Enter.
> 3. The cell will momentarily display Loading..., then return the result.

**Code:**

```
function stack(arr) {
  var flatArr = arr.flat();
  var filtered = flatArr.filter(function (el) {return el != "";});
  const newArr = [];
  while(filtered.length) newArr.push(filtered.splice(0,2));
  return(newArr);
}
```

**Named Ranges:**

[image]

**Example usage:**

GAMEWEEK1:

```
=QUERY(stack(FLATTEN(gw1_clubcount)), "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")
```

[image]

GAMEWEEK2:

```
=QUERY(stack(FLATTEN(gw2_clubcount)), "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY SUM(Col2) DESC LABEL Col1 'Club', SUM(Col2) 'count'")
```

[image]

References:

- [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [FLATTEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the simple explanation ! I will read more about this.